# IObservable<MqttApplicationMessage> does not contain a definition for 'Where'

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mqtt

I'm trying to implement MQTT in my Xamarin Android app using [this](https://github.com/xamarin/mqtt). However I'm getting error

> '`IObservable<MqttApplicationMessage>`' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type '`IObservable<MqttApplicationMessage>`' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Tried removing `Where` just to see if it will work, but instead getting

> cannot convert lambda expression to type '`IObserver<MqttApplicationMessage>`' because it is not a delegate type.

Tried using Ably.IO and PubNub and was able to implement it pub/sub functions but due to its message rate limit I'm trying this and hoping it doesn't have message rate limit. (ex: Ably 30-35msg/s limit)

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Series;
using OxyPlot.Xamarin.Android;
using OxyPlot.Axes;
using PubnubApi;
using System.Linq;
using Java.Lang;
using IO.Ably;
using IO.Ably.Realtime;
using System.Drawing;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net.Mqtt;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    var configuration = new MqttConfiguration
    {
        //  BufferSize = 128 * 1024,
        Port = 1883,
        KeepAliveSecs = 10,
        WaitTimeoutSecs = 2,
        MaximumQualityOfService = MqttQualityOfService.AtMostOnce,
        AllowWildcardsInTopicFilters = true
    };
    var client = await MqttClient.CreateAsync("test.mosquitto.org", configuration);
    var sessionState = await client.ConnectAsync
        (new MqttClientCredentials(clientId: "foo"), cleanSession: true);
    await client.SubscribeAsync("foo/bar/sampletopic", 
        MqttQualityOfService.AtMostOnce); //QoS0

    client.MessageStream.Where(msg => msg.Topic == "foo/bar/sampletopic").
      Subscribe(msg =>RcvdMsgtext.text=Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg.payload) );

    pubbtn.Click += async delegate
    {

        var message1 = new MqttApplicationMessage(
            "foo/bar/sampletopic",
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Foo Message 1"));
        await client.PublishAsync(message1, MqttQualityOfService.AtMostOnce);
    }

//note: Removed some parts but basically all i did was placed  it on OnCreate, changed it
//to async. In using Ably or PubNub "async" is not needed in OnCreate
```

Expecting a message to show/text change when publish button is clicked.

Edit: Was able to bypass this error by checking my references, Saw System.Reactive with yellow icon, double clicked it and the IObservable Error was gone, but produced error  that requires me to add System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions which I did at version 4.0.0 (read something about using this version to be able to build).

Edit: Added Using in code..

Now As soon as the code runs through this line:

```
var client = await MqttClient.CreateAsync("test.mosquitto.org",       configuration);
       var sessionState = await client.ConnectAsync
       (new MqttClientCredentials(clientId: "foo"), cleanSession: true);
```

I get an error

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000023 from typeref (expected class 'System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler' in assembly 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e')

Comment: Where extension method is in System.Reactive.Linq,you can add **using System.Reactive.Linq** on top.

Comment: hi! thank you for your reply, however I already have that and got this error

Comment: for this error (cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IObserver<MqttApplicationMessage>' because it is not a delegate type.) You should add using System; to top

Comment: Can you post the **using** part of this file

Comment: I'm currently trying M2MQTT now and cant make it to work either :(, but awhile ago I found out to resolve this error(Iobservable error) Checked "references and the System.Reactive has a yellow symbol, double clicked it and the error was gone, but produced different error which required me to add in nuget package, System.threading.Tasks.Extensions at a lower version (latest version seem to produce error)  after all that I was able to build without errors BUT....

Comment: yes I was able to build and compile, BUT as soon as it reaches  var client = await MqttClient.CreateAsync("test.mosquitto.org", configuration); an exception shows: Could not resolve type with token 01000023 from typeref (expected class 'System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler' in assembly 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e')

Comment: Was able to use M2MQTT can close this thank you

Comment: You can write the solution as an answer and mark it. This will help more people with same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to System.Reactive.Linq is in Using part of the code, as well as in references. For VS 2017 lower version maybe used, as this will also require you to add System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions

Also used M2MQTT as an alternative.